# How do I push a view controller from a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

When I click on a cell I want to push this view controller.

Here's my code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let user = filteredUsers[indexPath.item]
    print(user.username)

    let userProfileController = UserProfileController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())

}
```

I want to push `userProfileController`.

Note: This is a `UIView` not a view controller

Comment: you can get the viewcontroller from the view and push.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24590678/6642629

Comment: you can not push from a view.

Comment: Consider creating a callback/delegate to a view controller owning the view, and pushing the next view controller from that place.

Comment: This will definitely work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45582523/how-to-push-user-to-viewcontroller-from-non-uiview-class/45583476#45583476

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't push any controller from UIView. To do this you have to use NavigationController.

I'm assuming you have your UIView inside some UIViewController so one of the many options would be to create a delegate that will tell your view controller to do the push.

```
protocol MyViewDelegate {
    func didTapButton()
}

class MyView: UIView {

    weak var delegate: MyViewDelegate?

    func buttonTapAction() {
        delegate?.didTapButton()
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, MyViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myView.delegate = self
    }

    func didTapButton() {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(someVc, animated: true)
    } 

}
```

Comment: for myView in ViewController, have you just created a new instance of MyView at the beginning of ViewController class?

Comment: For creating a custom view for a ViewController, just use the method `loadView`. For more information, take a look here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview

Comment: you have not mention how did you get myView where from which makes the answer incomplete

Answer (score 0):

If your view controller in navigation controller stack and View controller holds view then you can follow
Block mechanism

```
func pushViewController(completion: () -> ()) {
}
```

Assign completion block from VC.

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(userProfileController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(superview?.next? as? UIViewController)?.navigationController?.pushViewController("your viewcontroller object", animated: false)
```

Comment: That works, but it's fragile. Better to give your view an owningNavigationController property, and set it up when the view is loaded. (You'll need to add supporting code in the owning view controller.)