# Prevent to create multiple instances from same type ViewController (ARC)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am working with `UINavigationController`. 
I want to prevent to create multiple instances from same type ViewController. 
If I have a `UINavigationController` with four children ViewController(s) **(A, B, C, D)** and another ViewController (**E**) and I navigate from `A -> B -> C -> D` and in **D**ViewController I will instantiate  **E**ViewController and I will present it .. and from **E**ViewController I go to **A** ViewController I will have 2 instances from **A**ViewController .. and I want to prevent it.

Here is storyboard with all ViewController(s):
[image]

How I navigate from **D** to **E**:

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "E") as? E   
self.present(vc!, animated: true)
```

How I navigate from **E** to **A**:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "aSegue", sender: nil)
```

I found some solutions as:

1) When I am in **E** ViewController should destory all ViewController(s) (**A, B, C, D**)

2) When I navigate from **E** to **A** .. check if exists **A**ViewController .. if it exists set as `rootViewController`, else create it and present it:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
var aVC: AViewController?
if let viewControllers = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.childViewControllers {
  for vc in viewControllers {
    print(vc.debugDescription)
    if vc.isKind(of: AViewController.self) {
      aVC = vc as! AViewController
      break
    }
  }
}


if let vc = aVC {
  let navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
  AppDelegate.delegate().setRootViewController(view: navigation)
} else {
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AViewController") as? AViewController
    self.present(vc!, animated: true)
}
```

3) Create singleton manager for each ViewController (example: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46467132/4062046))

```
class AManager {
     static let sharedInstance = AManager()
}
```

Hope you understand my problem.
Looking for a good solution.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Use an unwind segue to `A` from `E` or simply use `navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)`

Comment: @Mukesh you are right. I resolved my problem using with unwind .. I thought unwind is used only when current viewcontroller is in same NavigationController as destinatination viewcontroller. In my situation E ViewController is an independent viewcontroller and (A, B, C, D) are in same NavigationController.
You saved my day! Thank you very much

Comment: Glad it worked. Enjoy.