# NSWindowController: How to open only one time: macOS App in status bar

Tags: swift, macos, nswindowcontroller, nsmenuitem

I create a simple app for only status bar in macOS Swift.

I create a new NSWindowController and xib, when I call @objc function

```
self.aboutWindows.showWindow(self)
```

if I click it opens, but every time I click it opens a new window. How can I avoid it.

Same for another function of an NSMenuItem, I would like to start it only once.

Thanks

EDIT:

> ***ALL IN APPDELEGATE***

```
var aboutWindows = AboutWindows()

...

//TAP ON MENU ITEM
@objc func aboutWindows(_ sender: Any) {

    aboutWindows = AboutWindows(windowNibName: "AboutWindows")
    self.aboutWindows.showWindow(self)

}
```

Comment: How, when and from where do you instantiate the window?

Comment: @willeke When tap on “about” in app delegate by #selector(AppDelegate.aboutWindows()) (Because the app is only for status bar)

Comment: I mean how, when and from where in your code do you instantiate the window?

Comment: See [Avoid creation of multiple ViewController instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466660/avoid-creation-of-multiple-viewcontroller-instances-ios-swift)